# FOTEK SSR replacing the Triac

Tags: solid-state-relay, triac

I recently bought a few of FOTEK SSR-40DA relays believing that they are 40 A.
Anyway I've burned one of then connected to my boiler, and I've opened it, and it turns out that they actually having BTA25 triac inside, which is 25 A.

- I wonder if I can directly replace it with BTA41 (which is 40A)?

Comment: This may be of interest:
[UL warns of solid state relay with counterfeit UL Recognition Mark (Release 13PN-52)](http://www.ul.com/newsroom/publicnotices/ul-warns-of-solid-state-relay-with-counterfeit-ul-recognition-mark-release-13pn-52/). 
See also Big Clive's [Teardown of an eBay 25A Solid State Relay (SSR)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxEhxjvifyY&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: You need quite a large heatsink to carry that kind of current reliably.  Have/will you provide a heatsink and perhaps a fan capable of dissipating roughly 1W/A of heat without getting unduly hot?

Comment: Sounds like a fake one to me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is most likely not to having any problems with the replacement looking at the possible chematics and the datasheets.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please be more verbose with your answers and add reasoning to your claims. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could {directly replace it with BTA41 (which is <s>40</s> 41A) and @Transistor is correct, in that you seem to have purchased a cheap, fraud clone, that is one size under its rating.